# How to get rid of the Close Button of a Console Window?

Tags: vb.net, winapi, console, window-handles

I have a customer who is using some old but still needed 32Bit-Software, which is running in a Console Window. It is necessary to disable the Close button because closing the Console using this button causes some serious problems in this software.

I thought about the following way:

1) Find the handle of the active Console
2) Disable the Close Button with `GetSystemMenu` function

Maybe I'm completely wrong, but I did not manage to find a way to do that so far.

**Edit:**

The problem is just the Close Button. Of course users can also quit the program by <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> or Task Manager, but they don't do that. They do use Close Button, that's why I want to disable it.

Of course the best solution would by to disable all ways to cancel the program, but to disable the Close Button would work.

To start the program inside a Windows Form would by one possible solution, too.

Comment: Can you consider moving the window so its menu bar is off the top of the screen?

Comment: You can also make parts of windows forms be transparent so you could use a forms app to launch this dos program then set itself AlwaysOnTop, have a large see-thru hole in the middle of the form, and be positioned so the remaining border outline of the windows form hides the outline of the dos box...

Comment: There aren't a lot of details in your question but I'm guessing that the problems come if the dos app is force quit by any means, including task manager, so you might have to go to some considerable effort to make the computer that runs it operate in kiosk mode, disable task manager etc. We're going to need more details to really help out

Comment: You can start a process that runs in the console subsystem without having the system allocate a console for it. Passing `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` as the `dwCreationFlags` in a call to [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) does that. Without there being a console window you now no longer have to prevent a user from interacting with it. @cai There is no DOS program. The question clearly states, that this is 32-bit software.

Comment: By DOS program, I meant "program running in a console window"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with a *foreign* Window, you need to find it/verify it exists first.

We have different methods to find a Window. Here I'm considering [FindWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) and [Process.GetProcessesByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname).
[UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) and [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) provide other options, eventually.

Store the CMD Window caption somewhere, e.g., an instance Field (it could be a Project settings or anything else you can access at run-time).

```
Private cmdWindowTitle As String = "The Window Title"
```

→ `FindWindowEx` is more useful if you know exactly what the Window title is and it doesn't change over time.
→ `Process.GetProcessesByName()` can be used to find a Window using the Process name and then verify whether the `Process.MainWindowTitle.Contains()` at least a partial known string.

If instead the Console Window belongs to the current Process, you just need:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

---

```
' -- If the Console Window belongs to the current Process: --
Dim cmdWindowHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
' -----------------------------------------------------------

' -- Find it when the exact Window title is known: --
Dim cmdWindowHandle As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetCmdWindowByCaption(cmdWindowTitle)
' -----------------------------------------------------------

' -- Find it when only a partial caption is available: --
Dim cmdWindowHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
Dim cmdProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd").
    FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(cmdWindowTitle))
If cmdProc IsNot Nothing Then
    cmdWindowHandle = cmdProc.MainWindowHandle
End If
' -----------------------------------------------------------

' Choose one of the above, then, in any case:
If cmdWindowHanle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
    NativeMethods.WindowDisableSysMenu(cmdWindowHandle)
End If
```

**Note**: Here, I'm assuming the Process Name is **`cmd`** and the Window class name is **`ConsoleWindowClass`**. It may not be. Change these as required.

Since now the Window has no SystemMenu or Close buttons (we just hid them all), it cannot be closed using <kbd>ALT+F4</kbd> or any other means except using the Task Manager (or wait for it to close *naturally*).
To close it from your app, send a `WM_CLOSE` message:

```
' -- find the Window as described before --
Dim cmdWindowHandle As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetCmdWindowByCaption(cmdWindowTitle)
If Not cmdWindowHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
    NativeMethods.SendCloseMessage(cmdWindowHandle)
End If
```

`NativeMethods` declarations:

```
Public Class NativeMethods

    Private Const WM_CLOSE As Integer = &H10

    Public Enum WinStyles As UInteger
        WS_MAXIMIZE = &H1000000
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = &H10000
        WS_MINIMIZE = &H20000000
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = &H20000
        WS_SYSMENU = &H80000
    End Enum

    Public Enum GWL_Flags As Integer
        GWL_STYLE = -16
        GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
    End Enum

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, uMsg As WinMessage, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function GetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags, dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags, dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    ' Public wrappers
    Public Shared Function GetWindowLongUni(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags) As Integer
        If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
            Return GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex).ToInt32()
        Else
            Return GetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex).ToInt32()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SetWindowLongUni(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL_Flags, dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
        If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
            Return SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, New IntPtr(dwNewLong)).ToInt32()
        Else
            Return SetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex, New IntPtr(dwNewLong)).ToInt32()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetCmdWindowByCaption(cmdCaption As String) As IntPtr
        Return FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "ConsoleWindowClass", cmdCaption)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub WindowDisableSysMenu(windowHandle As IntPtr)
        Dim styles As Integer = GetWindowLongUni(windowHandle, GWL_Flags.GWL_STYLE)
        styles = styles And Not CInt(WinStyles.WS_SYSMENU)
        SetWindowLongUni(windowHandle, GWL_Flags.GWL_STYLE, styles)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SendCloseMessage(windowHandle As IntPtr)
        SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Jimi, but you assume that there is no system menu and no close button. But there is the close button and i want at least to disable the X-button.

You can find a picture of a standard dosbox with title and SystemMenu here:
[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au3E7nNN3rEyqhCS2MSdZbwS5SDy?e=JyVKCK)

Comment: I *assume* the exact opposite. I assume that the Window HAS both a SystemMenu AND a Close button. This code disables them all (making these Buttons *disappear*)

Comment: Excuse me please, Jimi. Then i misunderstood you - may be due to a a translation problem. I'll try your code ... Thank you.

Comment: No, you're right, I corrected that sentence because it was not clear. Now it should better describe the code intents and expectations. I've also changed the code a bit, the method calls are more *concise* now.

Comment: I tried your code. I copied it to a new console-project and built the exe. There was no error. Then i run the exe in a new DOSBox with the title "Eingabeaufforderung" and of course i changed the "The windows title" to "Eingabeaufforderung" as well, so that it matches. 

There is also no error on runtime but no change either. The Close-Buton is still there and working. If i click it, the MOSDOS-Box is still closed immidiatly.

Comment: Have you tried both methods to get the Window handle? Both with `GetCmdWindowByCaption` and `GetProcessesByName`? Have you verified whether one of these can actually get the handle of that Window? Are you sure that the Window Caption is just `Eingabeaufforderung` and the class name is `ConsoleWindowClass` (as described in a note, it may not be)? You have to debug your code. Put a breakpoint on the first line, go on line by line and verify the values you get back. This code doesn't throw if the handle is not found (unless you make it).

Comment: I made sure that "Eingabeaufforderung" is correct (as you can see in my link some posts earlier) 

I only tried GetCmdWindowByCaption so far. May be ConsoleWindowClass is wrong. 

I added the line "Console.WriteLine(cmdWindowHandle)" and that line return "0". I assume that this means, that the handle wasn't found. 

Then i tried the following:

Public Shared Function GetCmdWindowByCaption(cmdCaption As String) As IntPtr
      Return FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, vbNullString, vbNullString)
End Function

This returns allways "67176". I think this may be any window now?

Comment: After that an error is shown:

Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.OverflowException: Die arithmetische Operation hat einen Überlauf verursacht.
   bei Xweg.Module1.NativeMethods.GetWindowLongUni(IntPtr hWnd, GWL_Flags nIndex)
   bei Xweg.Module1.Main()

Comment: I tried to find the running Processes on my machine with "GetProcesses" and that code returns me just one process with ProcessName = cmd and ProcessID = 6208

If i start another DOSBOX, i receive two items:
ProcessName = cmd and ProcessID = 6208
ProcessName = cmd and ProcessID = 29888

Can this help?

Comment: I think i finally managed it by using "ThisProcess.MainWindowHandle" found by "GetProcesses". The complete ControlBox with the Minimize, Maximize and the Close-Button is gone now.

Comment: The overflow exception you're getting using GetWindowLongUni is probably caused by an application compiled as x86 running on a x64 System (which is strange anyway, since that method is built exactly to avoid that - unless you're passing the wrong handle, or IntPtr.Zero). Unless it's necessary for some reason to run as a 32 bit process, compile using the `AnyCPU` profile and untick the Prefer 32-bit option in the Project `Properties-> Compile` panel. BTW, in that code, commented out, you already have the Process way to get the handle of the cmd Window.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, i do not get the exception any more. 

I managed to find the handle of the active windows.It is sooo easy:

`Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As IntPtr


        Dim cmdWindowHandle As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow


        If cmdWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            NativeMethods.WindowDisableSysMenu(cmdWindowHandle)
        End If 
`

Comment: GetForegroundWindow is not the right way. You'll notice soon enough, without the need to explain why. Use the code I posted.

Comment: OK, i can use 'GetProcesses' and a following loop through all found processes to find the handle as well. It's possible to filter the found processes by the ProcessName (cmd) and by the ProcessMainTitle to find the right one. 

Of course i'll give your code with 'Process.GetProcessesByName()' a second look too.

Comment: The code provided, in both flavors, already does that. If you explain what kind of problem you have in the identification of the Console Window, I can suggest a solution. Note that this code works in Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 with a standard Console Window. If your Console Window class name is not `ConsoleWindowClass`, then identify the correct class name and substitute the value in the `GetCmdWindowByCaption` method.

Comment: As i described above, 'FindWindowEx' does not find the handle and returns 0. I made sure that the title is correct.

My console window is always a freshly opened standard console window with no program started inside that console so far. I posted a link to a picture above. 

The console window, i'm looking for, is always the open one. I want to start my program, that disables the close button, as the first program in this console window and after that the old program that requieres to disable the close button.

Comment: If FindWindowEx doesn't find that Window is because 1) The Caption you specified is wrong (cannot be partial and is case-sesitive) 2) the Window class name is wrong. This is something **you** need to verify and adapt as required as already described. If you cannot adapt these values, for some reason, use the Process method already posted and commented out in the same code snippet.

Comment: I had a thought ... May be there is a important misunderstanding in one of the first posts between us, what makes things more complicated as necessary.

You wrote: "to interact with a foreign Window, you need to find it/verify it exists first."

But the windows is not a foreign one - it is the one, in wich the program itself is running or should be running. My tool to disable the close button is always started in the same window where the close button should be disabled.

Comment: Well, that's a hell of a misunderstanding. You just need `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` in this case. I've updated code and notes in the answer.

Comment: @NilsSchuder If this answer solves your issue you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it for making this question and answer more clear. :)